# When to use 这道 for "this kind"

Tags: word-choice

The answer at https://chinese.stackexchange.com/posts/9675/revisions offers "这道菜" to say "this kind of food".  This looks like a very useful phrase, which I had not seen before (and if I've heard it, it did not stick with me, but that could easily happen).  How widely can you use  这道 for "this kind"?  What kinds of things would it apply to?  Is it informal, slangy, quite formal?

Comment: If you want to say "This kind of dish" rather than "this dish", you can say 这种菜

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this kind of food` seems weird.

`道` is the measure word for `菜` here, so `这道菜` just means `this food/dish`.

Comment: 道 is not limited to 菜. e.g. 这道题 这道公式, etc.